# How to display only grid tab on UIColorPickerViewController in Swift/iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, color-picker

I used the new `UIColorPickerViewController` in iOS 14.

I would like to display to the user only the first tab of picker (Grid color part) without other tabs.

Is it possible ?
How to get this rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Apple documentation for [UIColorPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolorpickerviewcontroller) it is not possible.

You could only set a `selectedColor` and `supportsAlpha` parameters.